# Serving squid proxy behind HTTP load balancer

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, squid, digital-ocean

I want to build a system where we have 3 squid proxies server running behind [load balancer](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/load-balancers/).
Currently squid proxy is running on http port, (help for https_port is also appreciated)

```
dns_v4_first on
acl loadbalancer src 174.138.123.136/32  

# allow only https ports
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy

acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow authenticated
http_access deny all
http_port 8080
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
```

When I provide the target url in https it is working, otherwise its giving error from loadbalancer ip.

```bash
curl -x http://user:pass@lb_ip:8080 https://ifconfig.me  # works
curl -x http://user:pass@lb_ip:8080 http://ifconfig.me   # does not work
```

The error in second case is

```html
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="/">/</a></p>
```

When I tried appending `/test` path in the example. It is confirmed that origin is getting stripped when using `http://`

```bash
curl -sx http://user:pass@lb_ip:8080 http://ifconfig.me/test | grep /test

<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="/test">/test</a></p>
```

But direct usage works in both case

```bash
curl -x http://user:pass@direct_ip:8080 https://ifconfig.me  # works
curl -x http://user:pass@direct_ip:8080 http://ifconfig.me   # works
```

Comment: Most likely your load balancer can't work as a HTTP proxy and strips full URL from HTTP requests, but you didn't provide any information about what kind of load balancer you are using.

Comment: I am using HTTP load balancer from [DO](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/load-balancers/)